# Meaning of evaluation metrics in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am pretty much a beginner in tensorflow and simply following a tutorial. There is no problem with my code but I have a question regarding the output

```
accuracy: 0.95614034
accuracy_baseline: 0.6666666
auc: 0.97714674
auc_precision_recall: 0.97176754
average_loss: 0.23083039
global_step: 760
label/mean: 0.33333334
loss: 6.578666
prediction/mean: 0.3428335
```

I would like to know what `prediction/mean` and `label/mean` represents?

Thank you in advance

Comment: They are just mean of your prediction and your input labels (should have been encoded and converted) calculated by [`tf.metrics.mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/mean). What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 2):

The `prediction`is the output of the network. When you feed in many inputs after each other you get many outputs (predictions). The `prediction/mean` is just the sum of all these outputs divided by the number of outputs.
The `lablel` is the value which the network should output/predict for a given input. Again you can sum them up and divide them by the number of elements in order to get the `label/mean` of the labels.
When you compare the `prediction/mean` with the `label/mean` you can find out how efficient your net was.